# How to send body request as string in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-7

My situation is

- using Laravel 7
- want to use Shopee API

Sending a request in Laravel should be like this

```
$res = Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $secret_key
    ])->post($api_url, [
        "ordersn_list" => [$order_no],
        "shopid" => $shop_id,
        "partner_id" => $partner_id,
        "timestamp" => $timestamp
    ]);
```

But Shopee API needs no space in the body part (cannot send as JSON format). I have tried

```
$res = Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $secret_key
    ])->post($api_url, $body_string);
```

It does not work because it must be an array. return error `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest::post() must be of the type array, string given`
.

Comment: Can you please explain `But Shopee API needs no space in the body part`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = [
    "ordersn_list" => [$order_no],
    "shopid" => $shop_id,
    "partner_id" => $partner_id,
    "timestamp" => $timestamp
];

$res = Http
    ::asJson()
    ->withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => $secret_key
    ])
    ->post($api_url, $data);
```

Or:

```
$data = [
    "ordersn_list" => [$order_no],
    "shopid" => $shop_id,
    "partner_id" => $partner_id,
    "timestamp" => $timestamp
];

$res = Http
    ::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => $secret_key
    ])
    ->withBody(json_encode($data), 'application/json')
    ->post($api_url);
```